# How to automatically change the project name and rev in the output file name in Altium 22

Tags: altium

How could I make the project name and rev name change (possibly from the parameters) in the output generation file names in Altium 22?

Right now I rename them individually but that's not very fun.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done in outjob (as you already suspected).

Create a 'container' that configures the output job - like I have for this PDF output:
[image]

Right-click on the output container of a manually managed output, and select 'Properties'.

In the pop-up properties window edit the output filename with a mixture of text strings, special strings, and **Project Parameters**, as you see fit:

[image]

My text string, in this case is:

```
=ProjectName+'_'+VariantName+_+PCBRev+'-'+MinorRev+'.pdf'
```

(Notice how single characters need not be quote-wrapped.   ¯\*(ツ)*/¯ )

Comment: Oh... This is in Altium 21.5.1, as I decided to stop paying for new versions.  Maybe they've 'improved' 22 since...  YMMV

Comment: Yeah, the new versions a annoying. They took out the compare/merge stuff in 23 because it didn't work and moved it to beta. Moving such a significant piece of the features back to beta (they worked well in 17 why did they break it?). Some of the high speed stuff is nice, but my biggest concern is the newest versions of altium are buggy, even 22 will die when you press the undo button, so save your work.

Comment: Ya, I got tired (after 20 years of Protel, then Altium) of paying for the same disappointments.  Two words (well one, really): Ki Cad.  V7 has been great for me.  Fits my situation nicely.